# PostgreSQL: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts in codeigniter using exist function

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter-3

So, I have this code

```
$this->db->query('SELECT id_anggota FROM karyawan WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT id_anggota FROM pengunduran_diri WHERE tgl_pengunduran <= '.$row->end_date.')');
```

the thing is I want to make a count data per period, as it's an HRD program, one field shows the sum of the workers per period as we know the company will gain and lose worker eventually. Yet I got confused by this error. Anyone can help me?
P.S it's inside the foreach

Comment: What is the value/type of `end_date` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen date

Comment: end_date: 2019-07-31
tgl_pengunduran: 2019-08-01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date literals in Postgres are surrounded by single quotes, which your query is not doing.  But beyond this, you should ideally be using a prepared statement here, which handles proper escaping of literals for you.  Codeigniter does not support prepared statements, but it does support query bindings:

```
$sql =  "SELECT id_anggota FROM karyawan WHERE EXISTS (";
$sql .= "    SELECT 1 FROM pengunduran_diri WHERE tgl_pengunduran <= ?)";
$this->db->query($sql, array($row->end_date));
```